# Spoof location on device

Tags: android

How do apps like Fake Location spoof their location in a way that fools other apps like Google Maps, FourSquare and Facebook into thinking that this location is valid?

I have searched lots of similar questions and a lot of answers are around making your own mock location provider which I tried but Google Maps is still at the correct location not the fake.

To be clear I dont want my fake location provider inside of my main app, I want to be able to spoof the location to fool other apps that are not directly linked to believe this location is the valid one

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: I am testing geofences so want to be able to make the location follow a route that eventually goes into the geofence and test if it triggers it

Comment: This you can do inside the application, there is  no need to send it to anothe rapplication

Comment: I don't really want test code inside the app

Comment: Why dont you use the android GPS simulator?